# How to create a simple skype bot with python and bot framework

Tags: python, botframework, skype

I am trying to create a very simple bot in skype with botframework using python.
Here are the steps i did.

- Created a channels bot in resources.

[image]

- Created a simple python web service using flask to receive the message from the bot. Exposed it over ngrok and added the same in the messaging endpoint.

[image]

- I tested the bot from web chat and i am getting a json in my python webservice

  ```
  {
  "recipient": {
  "id": "txBot@b0X6R31x6uQ", 
  "name": "txBot"
   }, 
  "from": {
  "id": "1xFUIEqdQfv", 
  "name": "You"
   }, 
   "entities": [
      {
      "supportsTts": true, 
      "supportsListening": true, 
      "type": "ClientCapabilities", 
      "requiresBotState": true
      }
   ], 
  "locale": "en", 
  "timestamp": "2018-11-22T13:00:42.9086958Z", 
  "channelId": "webchat", 
  "channelData": {
  "clientActivityId": "1542891640077.5912976099256072.0"
  }, 
  "conversation": {
      "id": "b5b52b9e464b4e958b1219dadedfffce"
  }, 
  "serviceUrl": "https://webchat.botframework.com/", 
  "text": "hello from test", 
  "textFormat": "plain", 
  "type": "message", 
  "id": "b5b52b9e464b4e958b1219dadedfffce|0000002"
  }
  ```
- I am able to process this json and able to get the user input "hello from test" in this example to my webservice.

What i want to do is to return the same to my web chat bot from python.

I referred the below tutorial as well. I am able to post response back but i am not getting it in the bot.

python code of backend as below

```
import urllib
import json

import requests
import urllib2, json
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import make_response

# Flask app should start in global layout
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    print "came inside"
    req = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)
    print("Request:")
    print(json.dumps(req, indent=4))
    service_url=""
    if req['type']=='conversationUpdate':
            return ''

    else:
            print "got input as : ",str(req['text'])
            payload = build_text_message_payload(req, req['text'])
            print "---- calling service url ----"
            #service_url = build_service_url2(req['serviceUrl'],req['conversation']['id'],req['id'])
            service_url = build_service_url2(req['serviceUrl'],req['conversation']['id'])


    print "---- Payload ----"
    print payload
    # where we are going to send our request
    print "---- Service url ----"
    print service_url
    # let's send the message
    response = send_to_conversation(service_url, payload)

    print "****************"
    print response
    # always return a response

    #print get_auth_token()

    return "success"



def build_text_message_payload(data, text):
    """Creates a text only message dict"""
    payload = {
    'type': 'message/text',
    'from': {
        'id': data['recipient']['id'],
        'name': data['recipient']['name'],
    },
    'recipient': {
        'id': data['from']['id'],

        'name': data['from']['name'],
    },
    'text': text,
}
    return payload






def build_service_url2(service_url, cid):
    """build the service url"""
    service_url = '{0}v3/conversations/{1}/activities'.format(
    service_url,
    cid
)
    return service_url

def send_to_conversation(service_url, payload):

  url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token"
  headers1={'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

  data=urllib.urlencode({'grant_type':'client_credentials','client_id':'jhxzxk1b2-1jjk-44b4-88bd-566d09crs4sg','client_secret':'lpfgrpDBPxjsLLFC41}@','scope':'https://api.botframework.com/.default'}
  req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers1, data=data)
  resp=urllib2.urlopen(req)
  ans=resp.read()
  ans=json.loads(ans)
  token=ans['access_token']
  full_token="Bearer "+token
  headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": full_token
}
  payload = json.dumps(payload)
  response = requests.post(
    service_url,
    data=payload,
    headers=headers
)
  print response.text
  return response



if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.getenv('PORT', 5000))

    print "Starting app on port %d" % port

    app.run(debug=True, port=port, host='0.0.0.0')
```

I am getting the response as 200 once i post the response , but not getting the response in webchat.
This is the response i get in python code

```
{
  "id":"b5b52b9e464b4e958b1219dadedfffce|0000003"
}
```

What is wrong here ? No response at all

[image]

Got this reference for this implementation.
https://chatbotslife.com/microsoft-bot-framework-on-a-bottle-13fdcc3e04e

Comment: Are you saying your bot is able to receive messages but not send them?

Comment: Do you still need help?

Answer (score -2):

because ,as far as i know apps that based on skype bot sdk (dotnet based), should uploud to azure and then add to skype and it will be works ok. this sdk work with request and response with microsoft skype server.

see this video it should help you " https://iulia-codes.github.io/notes/guides/build-your-own-skype-bot-with-these-simple-steps/ "
i suppose  see this library that simplified this works with python " https://github.com/denissa4/skype_chatbot "